# ffmpeg from pngs... Error with subset of PNGS?

Tags: ffmpeg, movie

I have about 1200 pngs that I'm converting into a movie. Some of them are missing: i.e. - _00003.png, _00005.png exist, but 1, 2, and 4 do not.

The following command works for other datasets, but not my current set of pngs:

```
ffmpeg -i pngs/_*.png -y -vcodec mpeg4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -filter:v 'setpts=1.2*PTS' p3SN.mp4
```

I get this error:

```
Output #61, image2, to 'pngs/_00096.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #61:0: Video: png, rgba, 3240x2160 [SAR 3937:3937 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png
Output #62, image2, to 'pngs/_00097.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #62:0: Video: png, rgba, 3240x2160 [SAR 3937:3937 DAR 3:2], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png
[png @ 0x7fae93170e00] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Error initializing output stream 63:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #63:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

at image _00097.png. If I remove it, it just happens a little later (105).

I've checked the images by looking at their dimensions, etc. and all of them in this range look the same (I checked all those with _0009?.png).

Any idea why this is happening?

Here's the offending file (middle) and the one before/after:

[image: 96]

[image: 97 - the 'error picture']

[image: 98]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command will overwrite all of the input files with the first input. This is an example of why to use caution when using `-y` which will automatically overwrite files without asking you.

You need to tell `ffmpeg` to use the [glob pattern](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1):

```
ffmpeg -y -pattern_type glob -framerate 25/1.2 -i "pngs/_*.png" -vcodec mpeg4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 p3SN.mp4
```

- I believe the glob pattern option does not work on Windows, but if it has an equivalent to the Linux `cat` command you can pipe the output: `cat *.png | ffmpeg -i - output.mp4`
- You can use `-framerate` and `-r` instead of setpts if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that did it.

Comment: On closer inspection, the movie quality is terrible with those parameter settings... Not sure why... I'll have to play with it.

Comment: @earnric The default for `mpeg4` (MPEG-4 Part 2 video) is inadequate. For this encoder add `-q:v` with a value of 2-5 (lower is better quality and bigger output file size). Or use a modern encoder such as `libx264` (H.264), `libx265` (H.265/HEVC), etc. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Comment: Thank you ... yea, the mpeg4 encoder was the culprit. I just tried "h264" and that also gave me good results... I'll try the other suggestions. Thanks again...

Comment: So what would be the full command with a Windows PC? assuming you want all *.jpg into a .mp4 output at 35 FPS?